# Mapping a JSON-encoded string in the DB to a Dictionary property on my object, using NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have an object that maintains a property bag of various properties. This is exposed through my object model as a `Dictionary<string, string>` and is stored in the database as a JSON-encoded string.

What is the best way to map this class using Fluent NHibernate?

**Option 1: Map to a private field, do JSON translation in my object?**

Should I map the property to a private `string` field, and then do serialization to/from JSON in my object itself?

Pro: NH need only know about mapping a single string to a text column which seems easy enough.

Con: My model has to track the dictionary *and* a string, simply to support persistence.

**Option 2: Use some sort of Interceptor?**

I haven't done anything with NH Interceptors before, but I know *of* them. Could I use an interceptor to do the Dictionary/JSON serialization, so that my model need only know about the dictionary?

**Option 3: Use a different encoding strategy?**

Is there a different encoding strategy, besides JSON, that NH supports natively and that I could use to serialize my dictionary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to store your Dictionary as a single encoded column, use a `IUserType`. You would map the dictionary as a property using your IUserType. This [blog post](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2008/07/31/Entities-dependencies-best-practices.aspx) has a good example of implementing an IUserType.

```
Map( x => x.JsonDictionary )
    .CustomTypeIs<MyUserType>();
```

You can also map this as a collection of values. This allows querying of individual values from the dictionary.

```
HasMany( x => x.JsonDictionary )
    .WithTableName("entity_jsondictionary")
    .KeyColumnNames.Add("entityid")
    .Cascade.All()
    .AsMap<string>(
        index => index.WithColumn("name").WithType<string>(),
        element => element.WithColumn("value").WithType<string>()
    );
```

Comment: @Lachlan: I have no need to query on individual properties, so it seems better to just store them in a single text field. Would you create a name/values table even if the pairs would never be referenced except as part of this property bag?

Comment: @Lachlan: I think CustomType might work. According to (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/242022/nhibernate-mapping-to-custom-types), looks like I just need to create a `JsonEncodedDictionary` class with a few special methods... I like this approach, since it keeps the serialization code away from the domain object. Thanks!

Comment: @Seth if you have no need for queries on individual name/value then the encoded column is what you want.