# Non ASCII characters in C# identifiers Referenced by NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, enums

I have tried to enter non ASCII characters in C# identifiers, and the program compiles and runs just fine (at least at first glance). To be more precise, I use Croatian diacritical characters (čćđšž) in enums. I really need to use these special characters because I map  string enums as value objects in NHibernate. It would be really ugly to have to avoid these standard characters when showing them as lookups to the user. Before I start using enums this way on a big scale, I really need to know if there are any implications (hidden pitfalls) to such a programming technique (especially in regard to NHibernate)? Or, if you have a better way handling this, please let me know.

Also, are there any problems with tools used for refactoring, SVN etc.

Comment: can you use the Html character? is this a web app?

Comment: Something sounds funny if putting "data" in enum names. Not sure how NHibernate works, but it really does sound off. (Also consider that ASCII/English is generally the lowest-common-denominator code format). Interesting question about language support for internationalization, though (+1) -- hopefully see the specification pulled out.

Comment: @hunter   Interesting question. This might be a problem. I'll give it a try with MVC.

Comment: @Željko check out this little tool I put together that just spits out some html characters. http://hunterconcepts.com/tools/developer/html You can click on them and it will show you the &#... html equivalent

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The C# language uses unicode encoding, which means your special character will not be a problem. However, I like to keep my code in english without special characters. I am yet to find a problem which justifies using culture specific naming.

From the C# language specification:

> A C# program consists of one or more
>   source files, known formally as
>   compilation units (§9.1). A source
>   file is an ordered sequence of Unicode
>   characters. Source files typically
>   have a one-to-one correspondence with
>   files in a file system, but this
>   correspondence is not required. For
>   maximal portability, it is recommended
>   that files in a file system be encoded
>   with the UTF-8 encoding.

Section 2.1 ([Microsoft C# Language Specification](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=dfbf523c-f98c-4804-afbd-459e846b268e))

Comment: +1 ... now, quick, a section number and excerpt from [the specification!](http://www.scribd.com/doc/7783523/C-30-Language-Specification) :)

Comment: So do I, but as I said, I'm rather forced into this because of the enums.

Comment: @Željko: There are other ways you can map enums to values.  You don't _need_ to use your enum as the value.

Comment: @Jeff M  Any hint how to do this? I googled quite a bit on this subject and all the articles suggested using enums for value objects.

Comment: @Željko: Well you could create a dictionary to map enum values to the string values you want.  You could then pair that with extension methods to do the conversions so it will be easy to use.

Comment: You could create an attribute to hold the value. Take a look at this article: http://blog.waynehartman.com/articles/84.aspx

Comment: @Željko: I would also recommend using an attribute to map the string to the value. If the enum is held as the string value in the database then you can write a custom mapper for NHibernate to use to map the string to the enum (I can provide sample code if it helps).

Answer (score 3):

<s>I made this custom user type to convert safely from enum to int for NHibernate.You should change the function to use string instead of int. Then you could change the method "NullSafeGet" to make the conversion from the database value to your enum value. Making so, you could use normal characters for your enum values and user readable names in your database.</s> 
 **EDIT : I made the changes myself. You can use this class for your custom user type. You should implement the "SpecialConversion" method to convert from your special string to enum and vice-versa.**

```
public class EnumToSpecialStringType<TEnum> : IUserType
{
    #region IUserType Members

    /// <summary>
    /// Reconstruct an object from the cacheable representation. At the very least this
    /// method should perform a deep copy if the type is mutable. (optional operation)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="cached">the object to be cached</param>
    /// <param name="owner">the owner of the cached object</param>
    /// <returns>a reconstructed object from the cachable representation</returns>
    public object Assemble(object cached, object owner)
    {
        return DeepCopy(cached);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Return a deep copy of the persistent state, stopping at entities and at collections.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value">generally a collection element or entity field</param>
    /// <returns>a copy</returns>
    public object DeepCopy(object value)
    {
        return value;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Transform the object into its cacheable representation. At the very least this
    /// method should perform a deep copy if the type is mutable. That may not be enough
    /// for some implementations, however; for example, associations must be cached as
    /// identifier values. (optional operation)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value">the object to be cached</param>
    /// <returns>a cacheable representation of the object</returns>
    public object Disassemble(object value)
    {
        return DeepCopy(value);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Compare two instances of the class mapped by this type for persistent "equality"
    /// ie. equality of persistent state
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="x"/>
    /// <param name="y"/>
    /// <returns/>
    public new bool Equals(object x, object y)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;
        if (x == null || y == null) return false;
        return x.Equals(y);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get a hashcode for the instance, consistent with persistence "equality"
    /// </summary>
    public int GetHashCode(object x)
    {
        return x.GetHashCode();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Are objects of this type mutable?
    /// </summary>
    public bool IsMutable
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Retrieve an instance of the mapped class from a ADO.NET resultset.
    /// Implementors should handle possibility of null values.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="rs">a IDataReader</param>
    /// <param name="names">column names</param>
    /// <param name="owner">the containing entity</param>
    /// <returns/>
    /// <exception cref="HibernateException">HibernateException</exception>
    public object NullSafeGet(IDataReader rs, string[] names, object owner)
    {
        var value = NHibernateUtil.String.NullSafeGet(rs, names[0]) as string;

        // Put you special conversion here (string -> enum)
        var converted = SpecialConversion(value);

        return converted;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Write an instance of the mapped class to a prepared statement.
    /// Implementors should handle possibility of null values.
    /// A multi-column type should be written to parameters starting from index.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="cmd">a IDbCommand</param>
    /// <param name="value">the object to write</param>
    /// <param name="index">command parameter index</param>
    /// <exception cref="HibernateException">HibernateException</exception>
    public void NullSafeSet(IDbCommand cmd, object value, int index)
    {
        var parameter = (IDataParameter)cmd.Parameters[index];

        // Do conversion from your enum to database string value
        var converted = SpecialConversion(value);

        parameter.Value = converted;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// During merge, replace the existing (<paramref name="target"/>) value in the entity
    /// we are merging to with a new (<paramref name="original"/>) value from the detached
    /// entity we are merging. For immutable objects, or null values, it is safe to simply
    /// return the first parameter. For mutable objects, it is safe to return a copy of the
    /// first parameter. For objects with component values, it might make sense to
    /// recursively replace component values.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="original">the value from the detached entity being merged</param>
    /// <param name="target">the value in the managed entity</param>
    /// <param name="owner">the managed entity</param>
    /// <returns>the value to be merged</returns>
    public object Replace(object original, object target, object owner)
    {
        return original;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The type returned by <c>NullSafeGet()</c>
    /// </summary>
    public Type ReturnedType
    {
        get
        {
            return typeof(TEnum);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The SQL types for the columns mapped by this type. 
    /// </summary>
    public SqlType[] SqlTypes
    {
        get
        {
            return new[] { new SqlType(DbType.String) };
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

I use fluent NHibernate and my way to map my column with this custom usertype was:

```
Map(x => x.PropertyName, "ColumnName").CustomType<EnumToSpecialStringType<EnumType>>();
```

**EDIT: Here's a post about how to map a user type using a xml mapping file:**

[nHibernate mapping to custom types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242022/nhibernate-mapping-to-custom-types)

Comment: Any idea how to map this without fluent NHibernate?

Comment: @Željko Szep I never used a xml mapping file. I updated my answer to give a link to another stackoverflow post. I hope the other post will show you how!

Answer (score 1):

I'm just writing examples here to show how you can do the mapping.

Consider your enum where all values contains non-ASCII characters:

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    NonAsciiName1,
    NonAsciiName2,
    NonAsciiName3,
}
```

You could change it to do this where all values have ASCII characters:

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    AsciiName1,
    AsciiName2,
    AsciiName3,
}

public static class MyEnumExtensions
{
    static readonly Dictionary<MyEnum, string> map = new Dictionary<MyEnum, string>
    {
        { MyEnum.AsciiName1, "NonAsciiName1" },
        { MyEnum.AsciiName2, "NonAsciiName2" },
        { MyEnum.AsciiName3, "NonAsciiName3" },
    };

    public static string GetValue(this MyEnum key)
    {
        return map[key];
    }
}
```

Then your code would need small changes to use this:

```
// you probably had something like:
var myEnumValue = MyEnum.NonAsciiName1;
var value = myEnumValue.ToString();

// now becomes:
var myEnumValue = MyEnum.AsciiName1;
var value = myEnumValue.GetValue();
```

---

Or has DEHAAS suggested, use attributes which works in a similar way.  But then you'd have to use reflection to get the values which has a bit of a performance penalty.

```
using System.ComponentModel;

public enum MyEnum
{
    [DescriptionAttribute("NonAsciiName1")] AsciiName1,
    [DescriptionAttribute("NonAsciiName2")] AsciiName2,
    [DescriptionAttribute("NonAsciiName3")] AsciiName3,
}

public static class MyEnumExtensions
{
    public static string GetValue(this MyEnum key)
    {
        return typeof(MyEnum).GetField(key.ToString())
                             .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false)
                             .Cast<DescriptionAttribute>()
                             .Single()
                             .Description;
    }
}
```

Comment: M This looks promising. I'll give it a try next thing in the morning. The only thing is worrying me is that the Ascii names (non Croatian) would be stored in the database (we for example have "muški" (male) and "ženski" (female) as gender. I'd have to save them as "muski" and "zenski"  to the database.

Comment: @Željko: I don't know much about nhibernate but you probably don't have to go that far. If it's anything like LINQ to SQL, you could probably change the mapping from properties to columns so that your ASCII properties maps to your non-ASCII columns. I would think there's a way to do that.  Tristan's comment suggests that this is entirely possible.

Comment: M  It's more like Entity framework. I agree with you on this. Maybe enums aren't the best way to handle this scenario (though almost every NHibernate sample handles it this way). I'll try another approach.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I consider that a pitfall.

Showing lookups to the user and keeping a list of the possible (unique) items in the database can better be kept separately. Especially if your application is to support other languages in the future.

Not very object oriented you could have a class in your code that is a direct mapping between your enum and the value of the respective language, like in a nhibernate mapping like this:

```
<class name="DropDown" table="DropDown_Language">
    <!-- map onto the ENUMeration -->
    <id name="UniqueID" column="Id" type="Int32" >
        <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <property name="DropDownType" column="DropDownTypeId" type="DropDownType, Domain"/>
    <property name="Language" column="LanguageId" type="LanguageReferenceType,  "/>
    <property name="DropDownTypeDescription" column="DropDownTypeDescription" type="string"/>
</class>
```

In the DropDownTypeDescription column you would then put the values of the dropdown.

Hope I understood your question :-)

Comment: Yes, but I don't want to map full grown entities. It's simple value objects with 2 or 3 posible values I want to map (like gender, clothing size: S M L XL)

Comment: I understand. Just wanted to get attention to the future extension problems you might have when you map Croation enums alone and then you have to go abroad with your application in other languages. (in our codebase we do have Gender mapped)

Comment: I agree with you, internationalization would be a PITA with the enum approach of mine. If you look up Jeff M's answer, this could solve my problem (use ascii enums and have a localized string for presentation purposes that could be read from a resource file).