# Fluent NHibernate mapping: QuantLib.Date and Mysql's Date

Tags: c#, mysql, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I am using the QuantLib's [Date](http://quantlib.sourcearchive.com/documentation/0.8.1/classQuantLib_1_1Date.html) class in a `C#` project, and this causes some problems when trying to map my `Price` class to my `price` table in a mySql database.

The `price` table has three columns: `[id]`, `[date]` and `[value]` and the code looks like this :

```
//ENTITY
    public class Price{
        public virtual long id { get; protected set; }
        public virtual QuantLib.Date date { get; set; }
        public virtual double value{ get; set; }
    }

//MAPPING
    public PriceMap() {
        Table("price");
        Id(x => x.id, "id");
        Map(x => x.date, "date") // to be completed... ;
        Map(x => x.value, "value");
    }
```

Is there a way to specify to NHibernate how to map this class to MySQL's [Date](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/fr/datetime.html) type, using Fluent NHibernate? Sort of casting it before saving in or retrienving from the db, without having to change the entity's structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options

1. Create a custom type for nhibernate and specify it in the mapping as `.CustomType`. Therefore you'll have to implement a small interface which does the conversion to and from `QuantLib.Date`
2. You simply change the type of the date property to System.DateTime and add another property which read/writes to the date property but uses your `QuantLib.Date`,
   pseudocode:

   ```
   public QuantLib.Date QDate {
      get{
        // read from this.date and create a new QuantLib.Date
      }
      set{
        // write to this.date
      }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks, I opted for the 2nd option. However I would like to know more about option 1, how to specify a custom type for NHibernate?

Comment: You just have to implement IUserType, find an example here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/242022/nhibernate-mapping-to-custom-types