# How can I use custom objects with NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, domain-driven-design

Please see the domain object below:

```
public Class Person
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; protected set; }
    public virtual string FirstName { get; protected set; }
    public virtual string Surname { get; protected set; }
    public virtual System.DateTime DateOfBirth { get; protected set; }

        //Domain methods are here.

}
```

and the NHibernate mappings below:

```
public class PersonMap : ClassMapping<Person>
{
    public PersonMap()
    {
        Id<Guid>(x => x.Id);
        Property<string>(x => x.FirstName);
        Property<string>(x => x.Surname);
        Property<DateTime>(x => x.DateOfBirth);
    }
```

}

This works as expected.  Say I wanted to change the domain model to this:

```
public Class Person
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; protected set; }
    public virtual FirstName FirstName { get; protected set; }
    public virtual Surname Surname { get; protected set; }
    public virtual DateOfBirth DateOfBirth { get; protected set; }
}
```

Notice the primitive types are replaced with objects.  The reason I am doing this is to remove primitive obsession as described here: http://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/2015/03/07/functional-c-primitive-obsession/

I have read the documentation here (page 144): http://stc.sbu.ac.ir/AdminTools/Docs/Files/nhibernate_reference.pdf.  It is telling me to introduce a custom type.  I have also read this question: [nHibernate mapping to custom types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242022/nhibernate-mapping-to-custom-types).  I am still struggling to do this with NHibernate code mapping and hence the reason for the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at mapping them via [components](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Fluent-mapping#components)?

This might be an easier starting point, compared with a custom type, if your data's in the same table.

Comment: Before I mark your answer.  Do you know if it is possible to map an NHibernate field to a class constructor instead of a class property (I have used a class property in my answer below)?

Comment: Not sure about that. If you look here (http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-property) you can see the access strategies available. It doesn't look like the constructor is supported.

Answer (score 0):

Following on from David Osbournes comment; the answer was to do this:

```
Component(x => x.FirstName, y =>
                {
                    y.Property<string>(z => z.FirstName);
                });
```

NHibernate using the FirstName property of a class to map to the database.